# How can i preserve a coating of baked in powder on activated carbon pellets whenever it rains?

Tags: water, boiling-point

I'm trying to create pellets of activated carbon that have a coating of a soluble white powder. To make this I first dissolve a significant amount of this powder in boiling water to the point where the activated carbon is saturated with the powder and cannot absorb any more. Then I add some more and let the boiling water evaporate completely. This leaves a coating around all of the pellets.

However this coating will wash off within 10 minutes when exposed to falling water droplets like from the shower. I'm looking for biodegradable binders that are soluble in boiling water and could help to preserve the coating around the pellets whenever its raining.

According to chatgpt i could use starch but i don't know if that's very water resistant.
What cheap water resistant and biodegradable binders could i add to the coating to prevent it from falling apart whenever its exposed to falling water droplets?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a water soluble substance which is not soluble in water.

Comment: @Maurice I am looking for a way to preserve the coating.

Comment: But the coating is soluble in water.

Comment: @Maurice Yes but so are a lot of other things like water based paints. Water based paints has binders to retain the pigment. I need a biodegradable binder that can prevent the coating from falling apart.

Comment: Water based paints are not solutions in water. They are emulsions, or suspensions. The painting operation is irreversible.

Answer (score 1):

Water-based paints, and many water-based glues, are not **dissolved** in water, but rather are suspensions. When the water evaporates, the [suspended particles come together](https://justpaint.org/investigating-the-drying-process-of-acrylic-color-and-gel-medium/) to make a continuous, water resistant film. Depending on the film-forming binder, such as [acrylic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylic_paint), polyvinyl acetate, [milk or egg protein (in tempera paint)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempera_paint) and additives, the paint may be made less or more water resistant.

If you have a specific schedule for release of the underlying "soluble white powder", whether hours or years, that should have been in the question. As stated, *you* would have to experiment for your use.

If such a paint, as you have suggested, meets your needs, why not use it?